# Indexing a table for advanced search

Tags: mysql, indexing, database-design

Say I have a table `shapes` table with columns like

```
create table shapes (
  id int,
  region_id int,
  clusted_id int,
  color varcahr(60),
  edges int,
  x int, y int, z int,
  orientation int,
  created_at date,
  updated_at date,
  visible tinyint
  ...
);
```

I need to create an "advanced search" functionality to query this table that has more than 2M rows. Users can query based on a mix and match of all the available columns. Something like

```
select * from shapes where created_at between ? and ? and x+y < ? and region_id in (?, ?, ?) ...
```

There can be fields that appear in the where clause or fields that do not appear. That's the "advanced" search. Also, nothing is full-text. Assume everything is either int, date, boolean or enum.

- Assuming the shapes are distributed evenly throughout all the possible values for all the columns, what are the best practices to index this table?
- Do I have to index all the subsets of the fields in the table together?
- Are there other external services that could help improve the performance? like elasticsearch?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is no "good" solution.

Observe what they *really* search on.  Then make a few indexes of about 2 columns each.  When making a composite index, start with something tested with `=`.  Construct the query based on what form fields the user fills in.  Don't bother indexing non-sargeable expressions such as `x+y < ?`.

More:

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql